# Scheduling is not working?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

this is my apex class for scheduling to run every 30 min.but when i scheduled in salesforce it will run after one hour but i need to run my scheduled class for every 30 mins.anyone help me to gohead

this is my scheduled class :

```
global class SchedulingService implements Schedulable {

   global void execute(SchedulableContext SC){


    ServiceNowUpsert.GetIncident('xxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx');         
       String day = string.valueOf(system.now().day());
      String month = string.valueOf(system.now().month());
      String hour = string.valueOf(system.now().hour());
      String minute = string.valueOf(system.now().minute() + 30);
      String second = string.valueOf(system.now().second());
      String year = string.valueOf(system.now().year());

      String strJobName = 'Job-' + second + '_' + minute + '_' + hour + '_' + day + '_' + month + '_' + year;
      String strSchedule = '0 ' + minute + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day + ' ' + month + ' ?' + ' ' + year;
      System.schedule(strJobName, strSchedule, new SchedulingService());    
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Simply schedule two jobs, thirty minutes apart, as listed in the duplicate question I've linked for you. Suicide scheduling, as it's called, is risky at best. If your scheduler fails even once, your job will hang forever until you restart it. If you just schedule two jobs to run hourly (`0 0 0 * * ?` and `0 0 30 * * ?`) your jobs will always run and never require a manual restart.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try the below format :

System.schedule('Scheduled Job', '0 30 * * * ?', new ScheduledClass());

Comment: That will run it once an hour half past the hour.

Comment: thanks for giving the reply to all i w'll check and update